# run code on the fly

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

In chrome, when I develop javascript, I can very easily test everything by typing code into developer console inside browser.

I am looking for something similar in C# - I know that this may not be quite possible, since the js are just scripts, and C# has a compiled code, but hey, every time I want to test three lines of C# code, I need to open my test project and input them in `Main` class. Isn't there any extension or something, that would allow me to skip creating a test project and just allow me to compile my test code and run it separately from the currently opened work project on-the-fly?

Comment: You can use `dotnetfiddle` or `ideone`.

Comment: That is cool, thanks! Anyway it would be beautiful to have something like this built-in Visual Studio, wouldn't it? ;)

Comment: Also try linqpad http://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: Check out the intermediate window you can evaluate expressions or tweak values through watchers.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx

Comment: it is Immediate I think, @TysonWolker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are debugging your application you can use `Debug -> Windows->`[`Immediate Window`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx)
2. use online tools like [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/), [IDE one](http://ideone.com/)
3. use desktop tools like [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), [Snippet Compiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/), [snippy](http://csharpindepth.com/Downloads.aspx) by Jon Skeet

Advance Scenarios
1. Use Mono Command Prompt
2. Use Roslyn C# Interactive Window